# How to update nested object (i.e., doc field having object type) in single document in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have doc collection which have object type field named `price` (i.e., see below), I just want to update/insert that field by adding new key value pairs to it.

suppose i have this as collection (in db):

```
[
 {
   _id: 1,
   price: {
     amazon: 102.1,
     apple: 500
   }
 },
 ....
 ....
];
```

Now I want to write an query which either update price's or inserts if not exist in `price`.

let's suppose these as input data to update/insert with:

```
var key1 = 'ebay', value1 = 300; // will insert
var key2 = 'amazon', value2 = 100; // will update
```

assume doc having `_id: 1` for now.

Something like `$addToSet` operator?, Though `$addToSet` only works for array & i want to work within object).

expected output:

```
[
 {
   _id: 1,
   price: {
     amazon: 100, // updated
     apple: 500,
     ebay: 300 // inserted
   }
 },
 ....
 ....
];
```

How can i do/achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Is your input data an array like for example `var input = [{ebay: 300},{amazon: 100}]` or just an object `var input = {ebay: 300, amazon: 100}` ?

Comment: thanks, updated that in description in question. it will neither object, neither array.. you may say input is two variables each time one is `key`, another is its `value` which will on update/insert it will as key: value pair to under price. i will call for all inputs one by one..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could construct the update document dynamically to use the **[dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation)** and the **[`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/)** operator to do the update correctly. Using your example above, you'd want to run the following update operation:

```
db.collection.update(
    { "_id": 1 },
    {
        "$set": { "price.ebay": 300, "price.amazon": 100 } 
    }
)
```

So, given the data input, you would want to construct an update document like `{ "price.ebay": 300, "price.amazon": 100 }`

With the inputs as you have described

```
var key1 = 'ebay', value1 = 300; // will insert
var key2 = 'amazon', value2 = 100; // will update
```

Construct the update object:

```
var query = { "_id": 1 },
    update = {};
update["price."+key1] = value1;
update["price."+key2] = value2;

db.collection.update(query, {"$set": update});
```